# Have I installed ubuntu?

Tags: usb

I downloaded what I thought was a trial version of 12.04 (booted via USB) some days ago.

At that time there was an icon on the desktop inviting me to install Ubuntu. Unfortunately
that icon appears to have vanished.

So is there a way to check whether I've installed the full program?

Comment: trial version? as opposed to what? full version? paid version? Linux is always free, so whatever you installed, it's not ubuntu, can you tell us from where did you obtained your trial version? you seemed to have installed some software, ubuntu cant be installed on windows the way you described it

Comment: I think that the OP meant a "Live" version.

Comment: Did u use something called wubi?

Comment: @blade19899 apparently not, he says "booted via usb".

Answer (score 5):

Simple enough. Does your computer boot into Ubuntu **without** the usb drive inserted? Yes ==> installed. No ==> (probably) not installed.

Comment: doesn't always work, sometimes, especially when you're dualbooted, the system boots into windows because grub isn't well configured, happened to me many times

Comment: hence the "probably". When it DOES boot, it is unequivocally installed.

Comment: Ubuntu booted with usb removed so I take it that means it's definitely installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command on terminal.

```
lsblk | awk '$7=="/" {print $0}'
```

If it produces any output then you are in an installed Ubuntu system or otherwise Ubuntu is not installed on your disk(*You're in an Ubuntu live disk* ).

For Ubuntu live disk, the mountpoint would be `/cdrom` or something else.But for installed Ubuntu, the mount point should be `/`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Ubuntu is an operating system. Not a program.

Although it is not easy to say by the information you are providing, I would suppose that you are currently using some version of windows. I would be surprised if you have indeed installed Ubuntu without realizing - what may have happened is that you may have booted up a "Live" Ubuntu, which is when you run Ubuntu from a DVD or USB stick.

You can also check your hard drives through "My Computer" and check if there are any drives with files that you do not recognize.

Comment: Good point. - I edited my comment above.